# next-auth is deprecated. If you are not ready to migrate, keep using "next-auth@4"

Tags: authentication, next.js, oauth, next-auth

So I make a project using `next.js` with `tailwind css`. The project has a login/register function so I used `next-auth`. All package is the new version

This is my code for the api/route.js
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Xxh.png)

This is my code to register
[register code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig4Ba.png)

The package
[package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U70GK.png)

Help I have a problem.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BioAt.png)

I've tried reinstalling the package.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with version 4.22.3. I just installed a previous update and it works for me now.

`npm i next-auth@4.22.1`